# Why collectstatic uploads all the static files to S3 (only occasionally) when deploying on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I am developing a **Django** based project and have used **Heroku** for deployment. I have used **S3** to store static files.

Recently I observed a strange behavior while deploying my application to Heroku.

When I push my application to Heroku, while running **collectstatic**, it sometimes(**once in a while**) uploads **all files** to S3.

Its like, I do a push **now**, it uploads **all files**(all of them are not modified), then **subsequent pushes** upload *only modified files*. Then if I push **after X hours**, it again uploads *all files*(all of them are not modified).

Can't understand this behavior . Do anyone have an Idea how is this behavior justified ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The uploading of static files has to do with your settings. They probably define some S3 storage for STATICFILES_STORAGE. As for uploading some or all static files, that is probably due to the number of changed files. (Or a current bug in django-storages that incorrectly parses datetimes from S3)

Comment: Hey, I am pretty much aware about how static files and django-storages work. I have around 600 static files in my project. At max 100 or 200 files might change at a time not more than that. This works fine if I deploy on AWS but only on Heroku it exhibits such behavior. Please provide some speciific answer

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem to get a more detailed answer.